# Checkout the git staging area possible?

Tags: git

I'm wondering if it is possible to move into (checkout, not sure about the word) the staging area in Git, to be sure that the code being about to be committed is stable, correct etc.

Let's say that I have 3 files modified, and they are not related to the same feature. I'm adding 2 of them in the staging area. How to be sure that the code I'm about to commit can compile or else ?

Or maybe I'm in the wrong way to ensure that my commit is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is in your staging area is in your working directory too, so if you want to know your code is correct you have to simply... test it.

Run your test suites (if you have), compile, run etc. If it's working in a way you want, you can commit it.

Of course you can use branches for separating feature changes and then checkout between branches (it's always possible when you have clean working directory, checking out with modified files is only possible when there are not any conflicts, otherwise you can use `git stash save` and then `git stash pop`).

In scenario when you added some changes to staging area and also you have other changes in working directory in *the same file*, you can [stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) not staged changes with `git stash save --keep-index`. It will stash everything except staged changes so you can test only your "commit".

Comment: I disagree that the staging area is in the working directory. If I modify A file and stages it, then I modify A again, A in working directory differs from A in staging area.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use your working directory or staging area to do multiple things at a time. Always branch, branch whenever you need to do something as small as a semicolon change. Commit the chnages and move to other branch. You dont need to push the branch to remote.

This way you will be working with only on one thing at a time and dont have to worry about code compilation and dependency problems.

In your current case you can create a branch and commit your two files there then stash your remaining file and see if it works. If it does, you can merge your newly created branch into master and get back your third file by `stash pop`

Comment: Sometimes it's impossible to work only on one thing since changes can be related to each other, but should be commited separately. Also staging hunks/lines does not match to your policy; you can iteratively stage "ready" changes and then, like Maxime, you would like to know if staging area is correct, regardless to other changes in working directory. This is not real answer for the question.

Comment: Although it might be hard, but I dont think it will be impossible to work on one thing at a time. If its impossible to seperate means its related and should be commited at the same time. And this does answer your question which is asked originally about how to know if staged area is valid to compile. You later on added the condition in comments to Maxine's answer that you could have modified the staged files too in the working directory, for which as suggested by Maxine you can use stash with `--keep-index` for same.

Comment: You have mistaken users: this is Maxime's question and my answer :-)

Comment: Ohh sorry. I even misspelled the name its Maxime, not Maxine. Misinterpreted by reading only comments to your answer.....